# PopUp window to be opened to touches within an Imageview

Tags: java, android, popup, imageview, zooming

I have a big image which contains different sections. What I want is different PopUps should open when the user touches different sections of the ImageView. For instance, see this Image below:

[image]

In this image, what I want is that when the user clicks 1st square, Popup 1 should open, on square 2 popup should open. How to achieve this please.?
Moreover, I want the ImageView still be zoom and pan enabled. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Hello you can follow my this post . I think my answer will help you ::

[popup window from android options menu not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20968597/popup-window-from-android-options-menu-not-working/20969695#20969695)

For you I have edited the code. You can follow in this manner. If button will be Image and replace button with that :

inside onCreate()

```
Button btn1=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btn1);
Button btn2=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btn2);

btn1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
{
  public void onClick(View v)
  {
    initiatePopupWindow1();
  }
})

btn2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
{
  public void onClick(View v)
  {
    initiatePopupWindow2();
  }
})
```

outside onCreate()

```
private PopupWindow pwindo1,pwindo2;

private void initiatePopupWindow1() { 
try { 
// We need to get the instance of the LayoutInflater 
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) PopupActivity.this 
.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE); 
View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.popup,(ViewGroup)

findViewById(R.id.popup_element)); 
pwindo1 = new PopupWindow(layout, 350, 350, true); 
pwindo1.showAtLocation(layout, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);

btnClosePopup = (Button) layout.findViewById(R.id.btn_close_popup); 
btnClosePopup.setOnClickListener(cancel_button_click_listener);

} catch (Exception e) { 
e.printStackTrace(); 
} 
}

private void initiatePopupWindow2() { 
try { 
// We need to get the instance of the LayoutInflater 
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) PopupActivity.this 
.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE); 
View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.popup,(ViewGroup)

findViewById(R.id.popup_element)); 
pwindo2 = new PopupWindow(layout, 350, 350, true); 
pwindo2.showAtLocation(layout, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);

btnClosePopup = (Button) layout.findViewById(R.id.btn_close_popup); 
btnClosePopup.setOnClickListener(cancel_button_click_listener);

} catch (Exception e) { 
e.printStackTrace(); 
} 
}
```

Comment: But the Image I have is one single ImageView.. How to check which part has been clicked.?

Comment: it's very easy, please put a Transparent image on that image view on different portion with different id , like this manner <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageBlank"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/blank" 
        android:contentDescription="@null"/>

Comment: But then the Image will not be zoomable right.? Because then when the user zooms it, its coordinates might change as well right.?

Comment: on such way place this image on different area where you want. And do this . It's trick . replace button use imageview.setOnClickListener(...)

Comment: May be it will be drawback....... but zoom is necessary, You had not mention this on your question

Comment: I have mentioned.. See the questions last line. Sorry if you could not notice. Is there any way you have to achieve this.?

Comment: ummmmmm I think zoom is possible , can you try to do this by placing single blank image. Must use Relative Layout.

Comment: sorry I miss out the last line. I think zoom is possible ...... please try and let me know

Comment: But its not a single image right. I have many images and thats why I am unable to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use (though it doesn't seem to be the best way of what actually you are trying to achieve but still you can have a single image)

```
setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
```

and the event.getX() and event.getY() will give you the coordinates where you are clicking

for example

```
if(event.getX() == 100 and event.getY() == 100)
{ // show your popup}
```

But there will be a problem if you have multiple images
you have to know at what positions these boxes will be present, and you might face problem if the image is to zoomed